# McFadden's Pseudo R² - Comparability across different datasets

Tags: r-squared

Several authors in applied research papers claim that McFadden's Pseudo R² cannot be used for comparing models that are based on different datasets.

I have searched some statistics/econometrics-textbooks (Wooldridge etc.) for guidance on this issue, but I did not find anything.

Could you please give me solid references (statistics textbooks or seminal articles) regarding this issue?